# Treating Arrays of Instances Like Single Instances

Tags: java, design-patterns, syntactic-sugar

In Java I'm looking for a generic template that means arrays of a given type (say `Foo`), will allow instance method calls upon the array. Behind-the-scenes this would translate to iterating over all Foo instances in the array, and calling the instance method upon each one.

Perhaps some code will demonstrate this point better:

```
public class Foo{

   public Foo(){}

   public void Method1(){}

}
```

So you have:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Method1();
```

But could you make some generic template for your custom types that inherently made this kind of thing possible:

```
Foo[] foos = new Foo[]{new Foo(),new Foo(), new Foo()};
foos.Method1();
```

Which is essentially syntactic sugar for:

```
foreach(Foo f : foos){
  f.Method1();
}
```

My motivation is so that someone can use varargs such that:

```
someHelper(fooInstance1,fooInstance2).Method1()
```

Where `someHelper()` returns the `Foo[]`.

If each `Method1()` invocation returned a value, it would be even better if this was wrapped in to an array of return values (where `ReturnVals.size == Foos.size`).

In the worst-case I'd have to write a separate class to achieve this for each type I need to have this work for, possibly using interfaces to describe functionality that applies to single instances and arrays of instances.

Is there any Java magic, Design Pattern or Generic jiggery-pokery that can elegantly achieve this?

Further, if not, do any languages facilitate this inherently?

I appreciate it wouldn't work for all scenarios, but that's at the discretion of the programmer I suppose.

Many thanks

Comment: These strategies belong straight to [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). You can easily do like `array.each(function(item){ item.method() }`, for example - but not in Java afaik.

Comment: groovy which runs on the JVM does support this using a special operator.  I cant think of a way of doing it in Java for generic classes without using reflection.  I'm not sure if theres a way you could inject methods at runtime in similar ways that groovy/grails does.

Comment: Scala too uses this style of programming.

Comment: I am a lover of functional programming at heart so I guess it was wishful thinking that an imperative language would do the same thing inherently. I wrote a compiler in Scala for my Masters Project the academic year just gone. Is it the map function you are referring to @PhiLho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling for the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). You can find a componentized generic and reusable implementation in the project [PerfectJPattern](http://perfectjpattern.sourceforge.net) make sure to checkout the Composite [documentation page](http://perfectjpattern.sourceforge.net/dp-composite.html) and the [example](http://perfectjpattern.sourceforge.net/xref/org/perfectjpattern/core/structural/composite/Example.html) that matches the example in the GoF book.

Verbatim copy of the relevant part of the example, say you have IGraphic interface and a few implementations, e.g. Rectangle and Line, then you can do:

```
// build the composite
IComposite<IGraphic> myComposite = new Composite<IGraphic>(IGraphic.class);
myComposite.add(new Rectangle());                
myComposite.add(new Line());
myComposite.add(new Line());

// use the composite, invokes the IGraphic#draw() in the 
// underlying Rectangle and two Line instances
myComposite.getComponent().draw();
```

This is how it would work for your specific case:

```
Foo fooInstance1 = new Foo();
Foo fooInstance2 = new Foo();
IComposite<Foo> myComposite = new Composite<Foo>(Foo.class);
myComposite.add(fooInstance1);    
myComposite.add(fooInstance2);    
// invokes Method1 on instance1 and instance2 transparently
myComposite.getComponent().Method1();

// alternatively do
Foo myCompositeFoo = myComposite.getComponent();
// pass this myCompositeFoo around and do
myCompositeFoo.Method1();
```

Note that the `IComposite` reusable implementation holds the actual composite and it **does not** implement/offer the `Foo` interface, you rather have to get hold of it via the `getComponent` method. This is a small nuisance and it is needed because there is no other way in Java to create an instance of something (in this case `Composite`) that implements any arbitrary and statically unknown interface. The best I can do is give you a `Composite` that underneath builds a true composite component for you and returns your desired interface type `Foo`. This is implemented using Dynamic proxies, but the implementation is type-safe and fully componentized i.e. you dont have to create any new Composite arrays that implement your interface.

Comment: I did wonder about Composite, having worked with it before in a few contexts, eg. file systems, tennis scoreboard(games,sets,matches). 

In the example above isn't the type Rectangle equivalent to the array-of-instances class I would need to define in each case to make this work though?

Comment: Not exactly. Graphic being the abstract level with multiple specializations: Line **is a** Graphic and Rectangle **is a** Graphic, you can then create a composite that holds all the Graphic specializations.

Comment: Ahh, so what you're saying is that say I had a method that took a varargs list of Foo's, it could return the type of myComposite.getComponent(). Thereby, the calling code would need not know they interacted with a composite, but could call methods upon the returned item as if it were single instance. That looks promising. What about return values of methods invoked on the composite component?

Comment: 'return the type of myComposite.getComponent()' what I mean is, return the object from myComposite.getComponent() to the caller

Comment: And how does it handle return values from the invoked method, if that method is not void

Comment: Maybe take a look at the documentation. I feel I am reproducing the whole material here :D I have also spent some time helping you as others have ... you should show some love and appreciation by upvoting the helpful answers. But answering your question, yes you can handle the case where a return value is needed basically aggregating from all the returned values e.g. min, max, first, last, your own merge etc

Comment: Just wanted to be sure before I accepted the answer! I'm at work at present so I apologise for being a bit slow on responding/giving up votes! Thanks for your suggestion, I selected it as the answer because it's the cleanest approach IMO

Comment: I think I documented it well and you have runnable examples you can debug and learn from. Nevertheless feel free to ask anything you need :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with reflection.

Create a generic class which at runtime looks at all the public methods of T and injects into itself methods with the same signature and a body which loops through all its objects and calls the same method on them.

The problem with this is how to call dynamically created methods.  Since this would only be possible through reflection it means that any method calls in your original code would have to be done via reflection.

Comment: Another concern I have with reflection is the potentially time overhead as well? I think if I were to then let someone use this as an API down the line it might not be very user-friendly for the reason you state.

Comment: @HodeCode I totally agree, I wouldn't like to be the one using it.  It was purely a suggestion, one I am not even sure would work. :)

Comment: it's a welcome suggestion. I was looking for possible avenues to solve this problem and reflection is definitely one I thought might contribute to a solution.. I just like to use it sparingly!

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways for doing this, most use wrapper objects etc...
However if your desired type is an interface, you're in luck, this is actually doable
using [dynamic proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html).

E.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    B[] objs = {new B(), new B(), new B()};
    A oneForAll = createMulticastObject(objs, A.class);
    oneForAll.print();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T, U extends T> T createMulticastObject(final U[] targets, Class<T> interfaceClass) {
    return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(), new Class<?>[] {interfaceClass}, new InvocationHandler() {

        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            Object ret = null;
            for (U target : targets) {
                ret = method.invoke(target, args);
            }
            return ret;
        }
    });
}


interface A {
    void print();
}

static class B implements A {
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Invoked.");
    }
}
```

Obvious limitations are that `A` (that is the type of object you'll be using in multicasting method calls MUST BE AN INTERFACE.

Another obvious limitation is that the multicasting object can only return a single return from all those invocations.

Code may look ugly when it's all in one place, but `createMulticastObject` method is a method you can use as an utility method and `A` and `B` are already written anyway.
So `dynamic proxies` reduce the usual wrappers etc to:

`A oneForAll = createMulticastObject(objs, A.class);`

Comment: The link suggests this is reflection based? As noted on another answer just now, I'm worried about how easy that'd be to code with, and whether it would be slow. The limitations you note might also be a bit of a roadblock too

Comment: Well it fairly easy to code with in terms of code cleaness.
Other roadblocks: if you need all method invocation returns, can't have a nice generic approach. The requirement for the existence of interfaces isn't a problem for me because I tend to use interfaces a lot.
The slowness: it's about 40 times slower to invoke a method through a proxy than directly. Note that INVOCATION is slower, not the method itself, i.e. empty method is 40 times slower (few hundred nano sec), if method does real work the relative difference is much smaller. I use reflection to dispatch in RPC - not noticable slowdow

Comment: If you use reflection to invoke methods running them in a tight loop, then you'll notice the slowness, otherwise not.

Comment: Whilst I don't think I can use it in this situation, I am thankful for showing my dynamic proxies. I wasn't aware of them, and they may prove to be an answer to a future problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: Excellent example of dynamic proxy use is MyBatis ORM library (uses interfaces as mappers, which are then implemented by dynamic proxies to dispatch calls to DB).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the methods in apaches's [CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html). You'll have to implement an interface for each method you want to call on a list.

Example:

```
CollectionUtils.collect(foos, new Transformer() {
    public Object transform(Object foo) {
        return ((Foo) foo).method();
    }
});
```

Here I used an anymous class, but you can also implement Transformer in a separate class and reuse it.

I don't know if a version with generics exists.

Also try a functionnal language (scala, haskell, …). They make this kind of things very easy to do.

Comment: I think given the size of some of the classes, defining an interface for each method might make this very time consuming, and not practical in this case?

Comment: @HodeCode yes, but you can use this at least for the methods you use the most (unless you find a better solution of course)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any Java magic, Design Pattern or Generic jiggery-pokery that can elegantly achieve this?

Not really - not without a lot of boilerplate, meaning it's less code writing the damned loop yourself.

> Further, if not, do any languages facilitate this inherently?

Most functional-ish languages support something like it. In Scala, you could do `foos.foreach(_.Method1())`, where `foreach` is a method that invokes a code block on all elements, and the underscore is an alias for the current element. Runnable code: http://ideone.com/QRtPlK

In Java 8, you'll be able to use stream views of collection along with method references to do something like this:

```
foos.stream().forEach(Foo::method1);
```